# NameError after using input in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am learning Python this semester and this is my homework.

Can anyone tell me why my code is wrong?

**QUESTION:**
You want to know your grade in Computer Science, so write a program that continuously takes grades between 0 and 100 to standard input until you input "stop", at which point it should print your average to standard output.

**MY CODE:**

```
total=0
count=0

while True:

    grade=input("Enter Your Grades between 0 and 100 [put 'stop' when done]:")

    if grade<0 or grade>100:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue

    elif grade=="stop":
        break

    else:
        count+=1
        total+=grade

print "Your Average Grade is:"+format(total/count,'.2f')
```

When I run the code, the Python keeps giving me this messages:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You're missing indentation (usually 4 spaces) in the while loop as well as parenthesis around your last print function call. Are those oversights in the original?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3 code? You can't use `print` without parentheses in Python 3 and in Python 2 you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: You are also comparing a string (returned from input()) with ints.

Answer (score 0):

You're running this program in Python 2 where `input` evaluates the user input. So if you enter "stop", Python tries to find the variable `stop` which doesn't exist and raises the `NameError`.

There are more problems and you need to restructure the code. The first thing you should do is to change `input` to `raw_input` which just returns the user input as a string. Then you need to check if the user entered "stop" and break, otherwise convert the input string to an int and then increment the `count` and `total`.
    total = 0
    count = 0

```
while True:
    grade = raw_input("Enter Your Grades between 0 and 100 [put 'stop' when done]:")
    if grade == "stop":
        break
    # Skip if the string can't be converted to an int.
    if not grade.isdigit():
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue
    # Now convert the grade to an int.
    grade = int(grade)

    if grade < 0 or grade > 100:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue
    else:
        count += 1
        total += grade

# Convert total to a float for true division.
print "Your Average Grade is: {:.2f}".format(float(total)/count)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Learned few more operations in Python 2 as well. BTW, I reinstalled Python 3.

Comment: Ah, that's good. In Python 3 `input` works like `raw_input` (returns strings and doesn't evaluate the input (that would be insecure)), and `/`  performs "true division" (float division) so you don't have to convert one of the operands to a float and can just write `total/count`. Also, to convert strings to ints and floats we usually use a [`try:...except ValueError:`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) clause to prevent errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change `input` to `raw_input`

```
grade = raw_input("Enter Your Grades between 0 and 100 [put 'stop' when done]:")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 2.7, so use `raw_input` instead of `input`.  The latter evaluates the input, so `5 + 2` will return `7` instead of the string `'5 + 2'`.  Entering `stop` tries to evaluate `stop` as a variable, which doesn't exist.

Another note, `total` and `count` are both integers, so `total/count` performs integer division in Python 2 (Python 3 gives a float result).  If you want a floating point average, use `float(total)/count`.  One of the variables must be float to get a float answer.

You'll also find that `grade` is a string, so test for `'stop'` first, then convert it to an `int` to test the grade `grade = int(grade)`.  You might want to think about handling errors.  What if the user types `10a`?

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate first the string stop, try capture the input with `raw_input`:

```
total = 0

count = 0

while True:

    grade = raw_input("Enter Your Grades between 0 and 100 [put 'stop' when done]:")

    if grade == "stop":
        break
    if grade.isdigit():
        grade = int(grade)
        if grade < 0 or grade > 100:
            print("Invalid Input")
            continue
        else:
            count += 1
            total += grade

if  count == 0:
    print "Empty values"
else:
    print "Your Average Grade is: %.2f" % (float(total)/count)
```

I added different conditions for correct execution, check the lines, for example `if grade.isdigit():` for verify that the input value is a numeric value, when this evaluation we can work normally with any math calculation.

`count == 0:` for the error division by zero if the user write `stop` in first iteration.

In the last line you can use two different ways to print the values:

```
print "Your Average Grade is: %.2f" % (float(total)/count)
```

or

```
print "Your Average Grade is: {:.2f}".format(float(total)/count)
```

Comment: Maybe because we forgot to convert one of the operands to a float to get true division? It's really lame to downvote without an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I reinstalled the Python 3.